# Does the site cover "party games"?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

Does this site cover "party games" like Pictionary, Taboo, or Cranium?

Answer (score 17):

I see no reason why it shouldn't.  I'm guessing that we won't see that many questions on these games since they're generally less complex overall - we're not likely to get complicated rules clarifications.  But if someone has a question on it, it should be welcome!

Comment: How about games like 1000 blank white cards, mafia/werewolves/charades? Does this apply to them as well? I've been wanting to ask a few questions on these regarding a bit of game design and rules but they're obviously not board games or card games.

Comment: I would say 1000 blank white cards is a card game :-)  Anyway I'd be interested to see questions and answers on all the games listed above, and it seems doubtful they will fit on any other Stack Exchange site better than this one.

Comment: Oh, just saw the comments on the other answer.  Maybe they'd class as RPG??  I'm not really sure what the scope of RPG is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, this site should cover all types of games that aren't done on a Smartphone, computer, or video game console/handheld.

For the types mentioned above, there is [gaming.stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure this site should cover sports either... though the dividing line between board games and sports can get a bit fuzzy (crokinole? carrom? pool?). Also, RPGs are probably off-topic.

Comment: @BrianCampbell [RPG has its own site](http://rpg.stackexchange.com).  It doesn't make sense to duplicate scope.

Comment: I think online games (that could played be on a smartphone, computer, or console) that are direct digital versions of a board or card game should be allowed, as long as the question being asked isn't about some technical problem, like "I can't see the game on X site, instead there's this little blue Lego piece looking thing with question marks on it. What do I do?"

Comment: @C. Ross Yes, I'm aware. That's part of why they're off topic. I was just pointing out that saying "any game that isn't on a smartphone, computer, or video game console" isn't the only criterion we need; there are other types of games that are off topic too. Whether RPGs are on topic in board gaming forums is something that comes up often, and is often answered by "no, they should have their own forum", so I figured I'd just mention that now.

Comment: @kchau Yes, that's true. There is a separate thread on meta about that http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-questions-purely-about-online-versions-of-a-game-be-allowed. I agree that questions about online or computer versions of board games are OK.